# How to quickly reading 72 billion elements from numpy arrays into triangular matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have several 1D numpy arrays ranging from size 600,000,000 to 150,000,000 elements.

I want to write all these elements into the upper triangle of a numpy array of size ~381K x 381K .

I used np.triu_indices. It crashed my memory.

I then created a custom iterator to get triangle matrix indices as follows:

```
def generate_triangular_mat_gen(n_words):
    xgen_iters = chain(*[repeat(x, n_words - 1 - x) for x in range(n_words - 1)])
    ygen_iters = chain(*[range(x+1, n_words) for x in range(n_words-1)])
    return xgen_iters, ygen_iters
```

This method worked well. But, it is slow to read 1 element at a time and copy to the numpy array positions. Will probably take a day or so.

Is there a way to quickly get say, 600,000,000 elements from the iterator in one go. This should really cut down computation time.

Comment: Computation time is probably not the issue here. A 381k by 381k array storing eight-byte values (e.g. ints) will take ~600GB of space in a raw upper-triangular form. Do you have that much memory? What elements are you trying to store? Can you store data in a sparse matrix?

Comment: These are string distances. I'm trying to cluster customer names for faster search.

Comment: Do you have some access to supercomputers? Which ones? Please provide some [mre] in your question, and tell more about the hardware available to you

Comment: Unsupervised clustering can perform well on random subsamples of data. I'd suggest trying to find another way to solve this, unless you have a system for handling this much storage/memory.

Comment: I just have access AWS EC2 instances.

Comment: You may wish to think about distributed computing with Hadoop and Spark. You will read this much data into memory within minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to quickly reading 72 billion elements from numpy arrays into triangular matrix

## You cannot do that

72 billions is about 10<sup>11</sup>. Assume an element is a 64 bits word or 8 bytes. That means 10<sup>12</sup> bytes (within a factor of ten).

The latency of a typical DDR4 module is about 50 nanoseconds per 64 bits word.

Do the math. 10<sup>12</sup> * 50 ns is a long time. 50Kseconds, so about half a day.

And 10<sup>12</sup> bytes of RAM costs a lot. Do you have access to supercomputers?

Consider using some expensive [GPGPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General-purpose_computing_on_graphics_processing_units) with [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) or [Cuda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA). With luck and a lot of programming efforts, you *might* win a factor of ten.

### Perhaps your computation time could be lowered to one hour.

I have no idea if that is "quick" in your culture. In mine, it is not.

And you could need weeks of development time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Basile. That clarified things a lot for me. I think I will probably have better luck moving to a more appropriate algorithm. I was trying to create clusters using string distances for better search of similar names using Sklearn's agglomerative clustering API.

Comment: One hour is quick. It's a one time task.

Comment: Yes, but development time could be several weeks. OpenCL is a hard beast.